# ReadTextAsync method is not returning anything

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8

I am developing my first Windows8 app (XAML+C#), where i am reading a text file from ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder - i am using below code snippet to get the data but it is not reading anything even though data is there in the file on disk:

I tried debugging this code, after ReadTextAsync call line - nothing happening.

```
private static async Task<string> ReadData()
{
    try
    {
        // checking whether file exists on the disk or not
        if (IsFileExistAsync("general.txt").Result) 
        {
            string fileContents = await PathIO.ReadTextAsync("general.txt");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContents))
            {
                return fileContents;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return string.empty;
        }
     }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

            return string.empty;
}
```

Comment: Do you ***really*** want to swallow all your IO exceptions and return an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're (incorrectly) using `Result` instead of `await` in that code snippet.

I suspect that you're also using `Result` further up your call stack, which will cause this kind of deadlock behavior. I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that goes into detail of why this deadlock happens.

To fix it, remove all calls to `Task<T>.Result` and `Task.Wait`, replacing them with `await` expressions.